# For a degenerated CS amp with current mirror would the small signal model include the current mirror

Tags: mosfet, analog, small-signal, current-mirror, common-source

I am aiming to create an actively loaded degenerated CS amplifier and analyse the small signal performance in relation to maximum signal levels, maximum signal swing, voltage headroom requirements, mid-band gain, output resistance and upper cut-off frequency. I have created a degenerated CS amp in LTSpice, which I will include below. I am wondering whether current mirrors should be included when it comes to the creation of the small signal model. Also any advice about how the components in the below amp should be integrated into a small signal model would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: So it’s an nmos degenerated CS , so if you want to add an active load , the current mirror should be at the Top of the transistor, I mean at the drain… and that MOS connected to the drain can be seen as the ro in small signal